# 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. in the widget test.dart

Tags: flutter

i am writing an travel app that have several list of location detail and fact. and now I want to make a list view for the several list of location. but after writing the widget_test.dart tell me that I positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. i don't understand what it means in the widget_test.dart. i have ask a lot people but nobody knows. can you help. this is my code. and the error part is here

```
await tester. pumpWidget(LocationDetail());
```

my whole code line
screen file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'style.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'locationroutefile.dart';

const LocationsRoute='/';
const LocationDetailRoute='/location_detail';

class App extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: _routes(),
        theme:_theme(),
      );
  }
  RouteFactory _routes() {
    return (settings) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case LocationsRoute:
          screen = LocationListView();
          break;
        case LocationDetailRoute:
          screen = LocationDetail(arguments['id']);
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => screen);
    };
  }

  ThemeData _theme() {
    return ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(textTheme: TextTheme(headline6: AppBarTextStyle)),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: TitleTextStyle,
          bodyText2: Body1TextStyle,
        ));
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_tutorial/screen.dart';
import 'textSection.dart';
import 'image_banner.dart';
import 'location.dart';
import 'screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class LocationDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final int _locationID;
  LocationDetail(this._locationID);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final location  = Location.fetchByID(_locationID);



    return MaterialApp(
      title:'second tutorial from youtube ',
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(location.name),
      ),
      body:Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment. start,
        children: [
          ImageBanner(location.imagePath),
        ]..addAll(textSections(location))),
    ),
    );
  }
        List<Widget> textSections (Location location){
          return location .babi.map((babb) => TextSection (babb.title,babb.text)).toList();
        }

  }
```

widget test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:second_tutorial/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(LocationDetail());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

location file

```
import 'location_fact.dart';

class Location{
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String imagePath;
  final List<LocationFact> babi;
 

  Location (this.id,this.name,this.imagePath,this.babi);


  static List<Location> fetchAll() {
    return [
      Location(1, 'Kiyomizu-dera', 'assets/images/kiyomizu-dera.jpg', [
      LocationFact('summary', ';ldjf;ja;ldjf;lajdl;jf;adj;lakdjf;jad;fj'),
    ]),
    Location(2, 'Mount Fuji', 'assets/images/fuji.jpg', [
    LocationFact('summary', 'hflajd;lfj;ladjf;lj;dljf;aj'),
    ]),
    Location(3, 'Arashiyama Bamboo Grove', 'assets/images/arashiyama.jpg',[
      LocationFact('sumary ', 'aldjf;lajd;lfj;aldjf;ladjf;lkj')
    ]),
    ];
  }

  static Location fetchByID(int locationadfadfID){
    List<Location> asdfgh = Location.fetchAll();
    for(var i =0;i <asdfgh.length; i++){
      if(asdfgh[i].id == locationadfadfID){
        return asdfgh[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

location list view.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:second_tutorial/screen.dart';
import 'location.dart';

class LocationListView extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final variables = Location.fetchAll(); 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('location route file'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: variables
            .map((testing) => GestureDetector(child:Text(testing.name), onTap:()=> onLocationTap(context, testing.id),)).toList()
           
      ),
    );
  }
  onLocationTap(BuildContext context, int locationID) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LocationsRoute, arguments: {'id': locationID});

  }
}
```

location fact

```
class LocationFact {
  final String title;
  final String text;

  LocationFact(this.title,this.text);

}
```

hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you seem to be using your `LocationDetail` incorrectly.

In `widget test.dart`, you have written `await tester.pumpWidget(LocationDetail());` .

But, in your constructor, you have `LocationDetail(this._locationID);`. So you have pass this `_locationID` param whenever you are using your `LocationDetail` widget.

So use it something like this, `await tester.pumpWidget(LocationDetail(1));` . But you can replace the `1` with anything you feel is appropriate.

More on `parameters` in `Dart`, follow [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters).

Comment: Wow really thanks for your help and your precious time. Your answer is very useful to me.  My project now has no error already.

Comment: Glad to have helped :). Do consider accepting the answer so that it may help others with similar issue.